# How to adjust the spacing of grid lines in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

In old highcharts, the default spacing of grid lines are smaller than it currently is. It seems that there is no api to adjust the spacing between grid lines. Is there a way to work around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Position of gridlines depends on tick which are generated, based on data. So you can modify tick parameters (like tickInterval / tickPixelInterval etc)

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPixelInterval